# Views in AngularJS - How to make them work?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, angularjs

I am unable to make angularjs views work. They have a working demo at [AngularJS: ngView](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angView), but the jsfiddle they provide there doesn't work. I'm trying to play with it a little but still I got nothing.
Suggestions? Any links to a really working example?

Here's my code: (actually, theirs)

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>angular</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="ngView">
  <div ng-controller="MainCntl">
    Choose:
    <a href="Book/Moby">Moby</a> |
    <a href="Book/Moby/ch/1">Moby: Ch1</a> |
    <a href="Book/Gatsby">Gatsby</a> |
    <a href="Book/Gatsby/ch/4?key=value">Gatsby: Ch4</a> |
    <a href="Book/Scarlet">Scarlet Letter</a><br/>

    <div ng-view></div>
    <hr />

    <pre>$location.path() = {{$location.path()}}</pre>
    <pre>$route.current.template = {{$route.current.template}}</pre>
    <pre>$route.current.params = {{$route.current.params}}</pre>
    <pre>$route.current.scope.name = {{$route.current.scope.name}}</pre>
    <pre>$routeParams = {{$routeParams}}</pre>
  </div>

  <!-- book.html -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="book.html">
    controller: {{name}}<br />
    Book Id: {{params.bookId}}<br />
  </script>

  <!-- chapter.html -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="chapter.html">
    controller: {{name}}<br />
    Book Id: {{params.bookId}}<br />
    Chapter Id: {{params.chapterId}}
  </script>
</div>​
​</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('ngView', [], function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  console.log($routeProvider, $locationProvider);
  $routeProvider.when('/Book/:bookId', {
    templateUrl: 'book.html',
    controller: BookCntl
  }).when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
    templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
    controller: ChapterCntl
  });

  // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

function MainCntl($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
  $scope.$route = $route;
  $scope.$location = $location;
  $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
}

function BookCntl($scope, $routeParams) {
  console.log($scope, $routeParams);
  $scope.name = "BookCntl";
  $scope.params = $routeParams;
}

function ChapterCntl($scope, $routeParams) {
  console.log($scope, $routeParams);
  $scope.name = "ChapterCntl";
  $scope.params = $routeParams;
}
```

What am I missing...?

Comment: What do you see on the screen / console?  Also, the tutorial has a working example of this

Comment: I started to walk around the api docs and completely forgot about the tutorial. Will check it out ASAP.
The console shows no errors nor warnings. It just doesn't work. But it got something to do with the links! I am starting to figure it out.
Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jsFiddle works if you replace the links with absolute links--this is a bug in the Fiddle.

```
Choose:
<a href="Book/Moby">Moby</a> |
<a href="Book/Moby/ch/1">Moby: Ch1</a> |
<a href="Book/Gatsby">Gatsby</a> |
<a href="Book/Gatsby/ch/4?key=value">Gatsby: Ch4</a> |
<a href="Book/Scarlet">Scarlet Letter</a><br/>
```

to

```
Choose:
<a href="/Book/Moby">Moby</a> |
<a href="/Book/Moby/ch/1">Moby: Ch1</a> |
<a href="/Book/Gatsby">Gatsby</a> |
<a href="/Book/Gatsby/ch/4?key=value">Gatsby: Ch4</a> |
<a href="/Book/Scarlet">Scarlet Letter</a><br/>
```

Here is a working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZFHha/1/

Comment: You're right (obviously). And I noticed yesterday that it seems to work  the very first time (sometimes =P). It all about the links, definitely. Now I must figure out how to proper set my links...
Thank you very much for a working fiddle!

Comment: The effect of the relative links seems to be that they're appended to the current URL, which starts as `/`, so that's why they seem to work the first time. Happy to help!